# UI blocking when trying to save data in txt file in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface

I'm trying to save recieving values in Txt file in delegate method using the below code. Those are Integer values, i'm putting those values in graph meanwhile saving in txt file.
but saving values in txt file is blocking graph plotting.

```
NSError *error;
NSString *filepath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)firstObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameString];
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filepath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSString *writeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n %@",string,values];

[writeString writeToFile:filepath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

PS: I used putting this piece of code dispatch_async, then its not saving all receiving values

Comment: Maybe try using DispatchIO? Seems to be good for IO operations like writing to files and doing so on a different thread than main.

Comment: Whilst you say you put that piece of code in `dispatch_async`, what queue did you put it in? And what thread does your graph render in?

Answer (score 0):

If you are pushing on a thread and not all the values are being written, it sounds like a race condition with the thread. Try and do all your string processing on the write thread to make sure that thread is the 'source of truth' and has the most updated information.